# Two Spring boot modules inside a Java app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a parent Java app which has two modules each being a spring boot module.
Parent pom.xml

```
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
</modules>
```

How should I autowire a component from different module? Say we have their packages like `com.abc.app1.module1` for module1 app and `com.abc.app1.module2` for module2 app and a class `UserDetailService` annotated with `@Component` inside `com.abc.app1.module2.services` package. How can we autowire this `UserDetailService` component inside a class of first module.
Will simple

```
@Autowired
UserDetailService userDetailService
```

work inside module1 classes.

One of my doubt is about ComponentScan since till now I have only worked with a simple one module app. Do I need to setup any ComponentScan and where if needed

Comment: Add module1 as dependency in module 2. Also you can spring factories file or import annotation

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez  One of my doubt is about ComponentScan since till now I have only worked with a simple one module app. Do I need to setup any ComponentScan and where if needed

Comment: Yeah you need to scan it because spring boot scan the first module only

Answer (score 0):

If you want that first module knows second modules beans you must use second module as dependency of first module

Add this dependency in first module pom file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>first-module-group-id</groupId>
            <artifactId>first-module-artifact-id</artifactId>
            <version>first-module-version</version>
</dependency>
```